# uri 1160, iniciante utilizando visualg, repetição

Tags: loop, pseudocódigo

O problema está em https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1160:

> Mariazinha quer resolver um problema interessante. Dadas as informações de população e a taxa de crescimento de duas cidades quaisquer (A e B), ela gostaria de saber quantos anos levará para que a cidade menor (sempre é a cidade A) ultrapasse a cidade B em população. Claro que ela quer saber apenas para as cidades cuja taxa de crescimento da cidade A é maior do que a taxa de crescimento da cidade B, portanto, previamente já separou para você apenas os casos de teste que tem a taxa de crescimento maior para a cidade A. Sua tarefa é construir um programa que apresente o tempo em anos para cada caso de teste.
>
> Porém, em alguns casos o tempo pode ser muito grande, e Mariazinha não se interessa em saber exatamente o tempo para estes casos. Basta que você informe, nesta situação, a mensagem "Mais de 1 seculo.".
>
> **Entrada**
>
> A primeira linha da entrada contém um único inteiro T, indicando o número de casos de teste (1 ≤ T ≤ 3000). Cada caso de teste contém 4 números: dois inteiros PA e PB (100 ≤ PA ≤ 1000000, PA < PB ≤ 1000000) indicando respectivamente a população de A e B, e dois valores G1 e G2 (0.1 ≤ G1 ≤ 10.0, 0.0 ≤ G2 ≤ 10.0, G2 < G1) com um digito após o ponto decimal cada, indicando respectivamente o crescimento populacional de A e B (em percentual).
>
> Atenção: A população é sempre um valor inteiro, portanto, um crescimento de 2.5 % sobre uma população de 100 pessoas resultará em 102 pessoas, e não 102.5 pessoas, enquanto um crescimento de 2.5% sobre uma população de 1000 pessoas resultará em 1025 pessoas. Além disso, não utilize variáveis de precisão simples para as taxas de crescimento.
>
> **Saída**
>
> Imprima, para cada caso de teste, quantos anos levará para que a cidade A ultrapasse a cidade B em número de habitantes. Obs.: se o tempo for mais do que 100 anos o programa deve apresentar a mensagem: Mais de 1 seculo. Neste caso, acredito que seja melhor interromper o programa imediatamente após passar de 100 anos, caso contrário você poderá receber como resposta da submissão deste problema "Time Limit Exceeded".

---

Tentei resolver da seguinte forma:

```
var
  A,B,per_A,per_B,FA_ano,FB_ano: real
inicio
// Seção de Comandos
   A <- 90000000
   B <- 200000000
   per_A <- (90000000 * 3)/100
   per_B <- (200000000 * 1.5)/100
   FA_ano <- 0
   FB_ano <- 0
   repita
         FA_ano <- A + per_A
         FB_ano <- B + per_B
   ate FA_ano = FB_ano
       escreval (FA_ano)
       escreval (FB_ano)
fimalgoritmo
```

Mas não bate com a entrada de dados do problema, não consigo fazer de outra forma, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você tem que calcular `per_A` e `per_B` a cada iteração. A taxa de crescimento é em relação a população atual e não ao valor inicial da população.

Comment: Por acaso percebeu que `FA_ano` e `FB_ano` formam retas que se encontram na origem? E que elas têm inclinações distintas? Qual seria o próximo ponto de encontro dessas 2 retas?